# I cannot delete answers on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete

Sometimes I misinterpret questions and like to remove my irrelevant answer.

For the past few days I could not delete my own answers anymore on Stack Overflow.
The following dialog appears after clicking the delete button:

> Vote to delete this post?

Bug or new feature?

Comment: Have you tried to actually cast the vote? As the author, you only need 1 vote to delete a post.

Comment: This has confused me, too. It would be nice if the prompts actually made sense.

Comment: This got me too; a delete vote on my own post does indeed delete it.

Comment: This dialog actually makes sense after reading the comment by _Grace Note_, but it really confused me the first time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to delete the answer anyway (unless it was accepted, see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222)).

Otherwise, you should just be able to click "OK" on the "Vote to delete this post" dialog.

Comment: This is true but it is indeed confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments, I'm apparently not the only one confused. The dialog is indeed quite confusing. Maybe it should be changed to something more intuitive?